# Pulling information from two URIs using Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Let's say I've got one giant sparse matrix in HDFS at `matrixX` and another at `matrixY` and I want to do a giant matrix multiplication and write to `matrixY`. Can I draw from two different URIs in Hadoop? How do I do this? All the examples I've seen have one input directory and one output directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from multiple sources as below:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(jobConf, MultipleInputs.addInputPath(jobConf, 
                     new Path(MatixX),       
                     TextInputFormat.class, 
                     ColumnReaderMapper.class);

MultipleInputs.addInputPath(jobConf, 
                     new Path(MatirxY), 
                     TextInputFormat.class, 
                     RowReaderMapper.class);
```

Lets say you have to matrix A and B:

a11 a12 a13

a21 a22 a23

a31 a32 a33

b11 b12 b13

b21 b22 b23

b31 b32 b33

A * B = summation (row of a * column of b)

How about storing Matrix A as row major and matrix b as column major. Now you can  set keys as row number in RowReader and Column Number in Columnreader in next mapper and send it to the same reducer which will do the summation and write the output. You can do many other optimizations but that should be the first start.